# EasyMock unable to mock close() method on java.sql.Connection object

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, easymock

I'm unable to mock the `close()` method on `java.sql.Connection` object. My ultimate goal is to do connection pooling while running JUnit tests. This will eliminate connection overhead during unit testing as the code under test executes connect/close for every SQL request.

I have code snippet which demonstrates the problem.  It successfully mocks the connect(), but fails to mock the `close()` call.  Both connect, and close must be mocked to managed pooled connections.

Since the `close()` method does not return a value, I'm using `EasyMock.expectLastCall`.

The following code defines the mock, but the print statement for `close()` is never executed and my connections are closed.

```
public class ConnectionPoolTest {

    public static final String DATASOURCE_REF = "jdbc/cloudexDS";
    public static final String ref = "osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=" + DATASOURCE_REF + ")";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception 
    {
        //
        //  set up a simple database connection (e.g. DB2SimpleDataSource) 
        //
        DataSource dbds = connect("localhost", "dbname", "userid", "password", 50000);

        //
        //  now set up mock for the datasource to use the above connection
        //
        Context context = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Context.class);
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CEXInitialContextFactory.class.getName());
        CEXInitialContextFactory.setCurrentContext(context);

        try {
            expect(context.lookup(ref)).andReturn(dbds).anyTimes();
            replay(context);
        } catch (NamingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //
        //  mock the close()
        //
        Connection conn = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Connection.class);
        try {
            conn.close();
            expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {
                public Object answer() {
                    System.out.println("Close connection");
                    return null;
                }
            });
            replay(conn);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMakeRequest() 
    {
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            ResultSet rset = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSCAT.TABLES");
            if(rset.next()) {
                System.out.println("Count=" + rset.getString(1));
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail("Exception thrown, msg=" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * get a connection to the database
     * 
     * Note:  The ic.lookup is mocked and will return a database connection
     * 
     * @return  connection object
     * @throws NamingException
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException 
    {
        DataSource cloudexds = null;

        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            cloudexds = (DataSource) ic.lookup(ref);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cloudexds.getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * setup a connection to the database.  This will be used with mock
     * 
     * @param hostname
     * @param dbname
     * @param schema
     * @param userid
     * @param password
     * @param port
     * @return
     */
    private static DataSource connect(String hostname, String dbname, String userid, String password, Integer port)
    {
        DB2SimpleDataSource dbds = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
        //
        //  local 'docker' database
        //
        dbds.setDatabaseName(dbname);
        dbds.setUser(userid);
        dbds.setPassword(password);
        dbds.setServerName(hostname);
        dbds.setPortNumber(port);
        dbds.setDriverType(4);

        try {
            dbds.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail("Cannot connect to the " + dbname + " database, msg=" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return dbds;
    }
}
```

I'm using EasyMock 3.3.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could you let us know what are you trying to test here. I dont see any method call here that uses mock connection. (You just set the mock behavior, not calling the close method)

Comment: Indeed, the code seems to correctly mock `Connection.close`. What problem do you encounter?

Comment: I updated the post to included a more complete example.

Comment: Henri,  I think the code should print the 'Close connection' text if the mock is working.